# Can we integrate the Allure report to Maven based TestNG project

Tags: maven, jenkins, testng, allure

I have successfully integrated the allure-report to my Maven based testNG project, and report is successfully generated which I can see by running a jetty server and looking at my localhost. So the xml reports which are generated are inside the main project folder.

Now I am integrating the jenkins with my Test project, Now I am able to build the project from jenkins but not able to see the allure report in the Jenkins. I tried adding the allure-report plugin to my jenkins but I guess I am missing some basic config for allure-report and jenkins.

Kindly suggest if someone has got success in it.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to configure the Allure-Plugin as a Post-Build action in your Jenkins job. There you can set the folder where your xml-results are generated to in your project. Normally this would be "target/allure-results".

The rest should be done by the plugin...

Comment: Thanks Andi for your quick and kind response. I tried the same but not able to see these reports anywhere on my jenkins page.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird...do you get some kind of error message in your console output when running your job? Or do you see something like "Report successfully generated to the directory" after the test runs are finished?

Comment: I guess I am doing something incorrect with either jenkins-allure configuration or there is some version issue.
I am not seeing any error :(

Comment: Do you have reference of any document that provides all the steps to configure allure with jenkins?

Comment: Yes I got some success and now I can see the allure-repot icon on my jenkins page. But when I clicks on it I see an 404 error message. Because that report was not generated or the path this link is looking is incorrect as I cannot see any report at this path. Maybe there is some issue in my build command. Should it be clean test or clean test site. And from where we can tell jenkins to see which directory for report generation or rendering?

Comment: As the maven goal "clean test" should be enough, because building the report is done by the plugin..

But if you can't get the plugin to work, you could in fact do it with Maven: Run "clean test site" and then as an postbuild action archive the generated report folder. Then you can add a link to the archived report to your build history (e.g. with a Groovy-Postbuild Action). If you do it like that, you would not need the Jenkins Plug-in...

Comment: Thanks Andi, this is a nice suggestion but have a problem, We will not be able to see the results of past builds,

Comment: Are you calling the post build action to archive artefacts? And there you have to put in the files you want to archive. In your case this would be something like "target/site/*" assuming that your report is generated under target/site. You would have to archive all files in that folder, which is done by the * character.

Comment: Do you also have any idea of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020269/jenkins-not-able-to-identify-the-correct-directory-for-the-generated-allure-repo

Comment: I cannot comment in your other question, so i will do it here. Can you post your <report> section in your pom? And what have you configured in your Jenkins under Allure Report Step? And are you sure that the results are generated in "target/allure-results" (the default) or somewhere else?