# Jenkins not able to identify the correct directory for the generated allure report xml file

Tags: jenkins, allure

I have integrated successfully Allure report to my maven based testNG project and able to see that report using the jetty server.
But now I am trying to integrate the allure report with jenkins by following the instructions as suggested here- 
http://wiki.qatools.ru/display/AL/Allure+Jenkins+Plugin
I am now able to see the allure icon on my jenkins page but if I click on this icon I see a 404-'page not found' error.

I further debug the console output and see an exception occuring-

```
Exception in thread "main" ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.ReportGenerationException: Could not find any allure results
at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.AllureReportGenerator.generate(AllureReportGenerator.java:58)
at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.data.AllureReportGenerator.generate(AllureReportGenerator.java:53)
at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.AllureMain.main(AllureMain.java:48)
Command aborted due to exception {}.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:153)
at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.command.ReportGenerate.runUnsafe(ReportGenerate.java:48)
at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.command.AbstractCommand.run(AbstractCommand.java:52)
at ru.yandex.qatools.allure.CommandLine.main(CommandLine.java:46)
```

I guess this error is coming because jenkins not able to identify the correct directory of the allure report xml, and to correct that we have to modify the pom.xml so that it can tell jenkins what is the path of correct directory.

Someone please suggest what am I missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer. The problem was my jenkins configuration not in allure report. I was importing my project in a incorrect way so my jenkins was trying to find the report in jenkin's workspace directory but there was nothing.

So what I did, I re-import my maven project to jenkins as a free-style project and set the custom workspace to my actual project directory. Now everything works fine.

Comment: Using Freestyle project, I think we can only link normal Java Applications built via Ant but not via Maven. For that we need to create Maven project instead of Freestyle project. In this case how to resolve this issue ? because I am facing the same and I don't want to create a Freestyle project. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to fetch your Allure results path from your Maven project to Jenkins from `project.name\target\allure-results` and add it in Jenkins\Your Job\Configure\Allure Report\Result.

After that you will need to change Jenkins security setting in one of 2 ways.

By starting Jenkins from:

```
java 
-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" 
-Djenkins.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
-jar jenkins.war
```

By running this two scripts in http://Jenkins/script

```
System.setProperty("hudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';")

System.setProperty("jenkins.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP", "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';")
```

edit:
I just found 3rd way to do this. In your Jenkins folder open jenkins.XML and add

```
-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" -Djenkins.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
```

to arguments.

Edit:

pom.XML you asked for:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.siba</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.siba.selenium</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>selenium tests</name>
  <description>selenium tests</description>

  <!-- Change from here -->

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>
    <allure.version>1.4.23</allure.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId> 
        <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId> 
        <version>4.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency> 

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.14</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

    </plugins> 
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Umm I already followed these steps and again retried the same, but the same issue is coming again. Actually the problem is that the allure report is not getting copied to the jenkins directory and when we tries to access it, it shows a 404 'not found' error. I believe the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: Were you able to successfully integrate the jenkins with allure report. If so, could you please share your pom.xml?

Comment: I had the same problem and the issue was not pointing to the allure result that's located in your maven project. If you point to it, as I suggested, it should work just fine. I will add my pom.XML, but I'm quite sure it's not your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Angusiasty, your pom.xml is almost similar to mine. I tried your pom.xml and still facing the same issue. I further drill down and found the cause, The xml file being generated in my projectName/target/allure-results direct with the name UniqueId-testsuite.xml is not getting copied to the 'workspace' directory of my jenkins. I tried copying an old 'UniqueId-testsuite.xml' file to my jenkins workspace and it generated the allure report in my jenkins but the report was showing the older execution results as we were using an older xml. How to copy this xml file to the jenkins workspace?

Comment: I don't copy it at all. I'm telling jenkins to find my results in 'maven.project\target\allure-results'.

Comment: yep you are right and I am also doing so. but can't figure out why jenkins is not able to find the results in my 'maven.project\target\allure-results' directory. Could you please tell the exact string that you are using for this path  'maven.project\target\allure-results'.

Comment: where we can find the jenkins.xml file.